# Max value based on multiple constraints

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

I have a table with columns `ProductCode`, `OrderType`, `OrderLineWeight`, `Price1`, `FreightCost`, `Price2` and `LoadOutDate`.

I added another column below which gives them a rownumber (ls) relative to their code which puts them in order 1-n for each `ProductCode` based on date (with next sale date first).

The data is forward sales / pipeline. What I'm trying to do is return the largest value for the next date there is a forward sale for each code. If there's only 1 on the next date, I want that row. If there are 2 or more on that date, I want the row with the highest `OrderLineWeight`.

I've got to here (below) which returns the row based on max `OrderLineWeight` but haven't been able to work out how to return the max weight for the 'minimum' date.

```sql
SELECT 
         ProductCode
        ,OrderType
        ,OrderLineWeight
        ,Price1
        ,FreightCost
        ,Price2
        ,LoadOutDate
        ,row_number() OVER (PARTITION BY ProductCode ORDER BY LoadOutDate ASC )         
        ) AS ls

FROM [TEST].[dbo].[DataBaseName]
INNER JOIN
(
  SELECT ProductCode, MAX(OrderLineWeight) CodeMaxWeight
  FROM DataBaseName
  GROUP BY ProductCode
) MaxOrderLineWeight 
ON MaxOrderLineWeight.ProductCode = DataBaseName.ProductCode
AND MaxOrderLineWeight.CodeMaxWeight = DataBaseName.OrderLineWeight

ORDER BY ProductCode
```

Current result:

```
ProductCode,OrderType,OrderLineWeight,Price1,FreightCost,Price2,LoadOutDate,ls
0111,0,1644.9200,4.5882352,0.0000,0.0000000000,2021-04-21 00:00:00.000,1
0117,0,18.3170,7.0588235,0.0000,0.0000000000,2021-04-23 00:00:00.000,1
0157,1,14.2180,3.4411764,0.0000,6.1824852331,2021-05-07 00:00:00.000,1
0158,1,19.5810,3.0588235,0.0000,5.4922038375,2021-05-07 00:00:00.000,1
0160,1,9.7800,3.4470588,0.0000,6.1931247019,2021-04-23 00:00:00.000,1
0160,1,10.6680,3.4470588,0.0000,6.1931247019,2021-04-30 00:00:00.000,2
0160,1,10.7650,3.4470588,0.0000,6.1931247019,2021-05-07 00:00:00.000,3
0163,1,11.5800,5.7352941,0.0000,10.3243570458,2021-04-23 00:00:00.000,1
0163,1,11.3800,5.7352941,0.0000,10.3243570458,2021-04-30 00:00:00.000,2
0163,1,11.2890,5.7352941,0.0000,10.3243570458,2021-05-07 00:00:00.000,3
0165,1,14.2730,3.3823529,0.0000,6.0763106724,2021-05-07 00:00:00.000,1
0166,1,12.2800,2.6000000,0.0000,4.6638294749,2021-04-23 00:00:00.000,1
0166,1,17.2670,2.6000000,0.0000,4.6638294749,2021-04-30 00:00:00.000,2
0166,1,17.3930,2.6000000,0.0000,4.6638294749,2021-05-07 00:00:00.000,3
0180,0,18.0150,1.4705882,0.0000,0.0000000000,2021-04-21 00:00:00.000,1
0181,0,37.9580,2.3529411,0.0000,0.0000000000,2021-04-21 00:00:00.000,1
0182,1,6244.3000,0.8823529,0.0000,0.5200498954,2021-03-31 00:00:00.000,1
0182,1,7560.8000,0.8823529,0.0000,0.5200498954,2021-03-31 00:00:00.000,2
0182,1,4000.0000,1.0117647,0.0000,0.6007631067,2021-05-31 00:00:00.000,3
0182,1,4700.0000,0.8823529,0.0000,0.5200498954,2021-05-31 00:00:00.000,4
0182,1,5000.0000,0.8823529,0.0000,0.5200498954,2021-05-31 00:00:00.000,5
0182,1,5000.0000,0.9882352,0.0000,0.5860879774,2021-05-31 00:00:00.000,6
0182,1,6000.0000,1.0000000,0.0000,0.5934255420,2021-05-31 00:00:00.000,7
0185,1,1970.3600,0.6470588,0.0000,0.3732986021,2021-03-31 00:00:00.000,1
0185,1,2000.0000,0.7176470,0.0000,0.4173239901,2021-05-31 00:00:00.000,2
0185,1,5000.0000,0.6470588,0.0000,0.3732986021,2021-05-31 00:00:00.000,3
0185,1,1000.0000,0.6470588,0.0000,0.3732986021,2021-05-31 00:00:00.000,4
0186,1,622.2000,1.0000000,0.0000,0.5934255420,2021-03-31 00:00:00.000,1
0186,1,1000.0000,1.0000000,0.0000,0.5934255420,2021-05-31 00:00:00.000,2
0186,1,3000.0000,1.1176470,0.0000,0.6668011886,2021-05-31 00:00:00.000,3
0186,1,500.0000,1.0000000,0.0000,0.5934255420,2021-05-31 00:00:00.000,4
0187,1,794.8400,0.7647058,0.0000,0.4466742488,2021-03-31 00:00:00.000,1
0187,1,1000.0000,0.7647058,0.0000,0.4466742488,2021-05-31 00:00:00.000,2
0187,1,5000.0000,1.1176470,0.0000,0.6668011886,2021-05-31 00:00:00.000,3
0188,1,2449.7600,0.5882352,0.0000,0.3366107788,2021-03-31 00:00:00.000,1
0188,1,5000.0000,0.6470588,0.0000,0.3732986021,2021-05-31 00:00:00.000,2
0188,1,5000.0000,0.7647058,0.0000,0.4466742488,2021-05-31 00:00:00.000,3
0188,1,1000.0000,0.6470588,0.0000,0.3732986021,2021-05-31 00:00:00.000,4
0189,1,440.0600,1.1764705,0.0000,0.7034890119,2021-03-31 00:00:00.000,1
0189,1,800.0000,1.1764705,0.0000,0.7034890119,2021-05-31 00:00:00.000,2
0189,1,1000.0000,1.1764705,0.0000,0.7034890119,2021-05-31 00:00:00.000,3
0189,1,3000.0000,1.7647058,0.0000,1.0703672451,2021-05-31 00:00:00.000,4
0190,1,1000.0000,1.7647058,0.0000,1.0703672451,2021-05-31 00:00:00.000,1
0190,1,5000.0000,2.0000000,0.0000,1.2171185383,2021-05-31 00:00:00.000,2
0191,0,79.5990,11.7647058,0.0000,0.0000000000,2021-04-21 00:00:00.000,1
0200,1,19.0000,52.9411764,7184.5800,30.6073669149,2021-03-29 00:00:00.000,1
```

Expected result:

```
ProductCode,OrderType,OrderLineWeight,Price1,FreightCost,Price2,LoadOutDate,ls
0111,0,1644.9200,4.5882352,0.0000,0.0000000000,2021-04-21 00:00:00.000,1
0117,0,18.3170,7.0588235,0.0000,0.0000000000,2021-04-23 00:00:00.000,1
0157,1,14.2180,3.4411764,0.0000,6.1824852331,2021-05-07 00:00:00.000,1
0158,1,19.5810,3.0588235,0.0000,5.4922038375,2021-05-07 00:00:00.000,1
0160,1,9.7800,3.4470588,0.0000,6.1931247019,2021-04-23 00:00:00.000,1
0163,1,11.5800,5.7352941,0.0000,10.3243570458,2021-04-23 00:00:00.000,1
0165,1,14.2730,3.3823529,0.0000,6.0763106724,2021-05-07 00:00:00.000,1
0166,1,12.2800,2.6000000,0.0000,4.6638294749,2021-04-23 00:00:00.000,1
0180,0,18.0150,1.4705882,0.0000,0.0000000000,2021-04-21 00:00:00.000,1
0181,0,37.9580,2.3529411,0.0000,0.0000000000,2021-04-21 00:00:00.000,1
0182,1,7560.8000,0.8823529,0.0000,0.5200498954,2021-03-31 00:00:00.000,2
0185,1,1970.3600,0.6470588,0.0000,0.3732986021,2021-03-31 00:00:00.000,1
0186,1,622.2000,1.0000000,0.0000,0.5934255420,2021-03-31 00:00:00.000,1
0187,1,794.8400,0.7647058,0.0000,0.4466742488,2021-03-31 00:00:00.000,1
0188,1,2449.7600,0.5882352,0.0000,0.3366107788,2021-03-31 00:00:00.000,1
0189,1,440.0600,1.1764705,0.0000,0.7034890119,2021-03-31 00:00:00.000,1
0190,1,5000.0000,2.0000000,0.0000,1.2171185383,2021-05-31 00:00:00.000,2
0191,0,79.5990,11.7647058,0.0000,0.0000000000,2021-04-21 00:00:00.000,1
0200,1,19.0000,52.9411764,7184.5800,30.6073669149,2021-03-29 00:00:00.000,1
```

Comment: Please show sample data and expected results (as formatted text).

Comment: Done. Thanks for the fast response.

Comment: It's not clear exactly what you are trying to do.  I *think* what you are trying to do is for each product code return the earliest order line for that product code and if there is more than one order line on the earliest date for that product code return the 1 with the highest weight?  Is that correct?

Comment: That is exactly correct. Thank you.